# Cannot use import statement outside a module - jest + nextj.js

Tags: next.js, jestjs, sitecore, react-testing-library, ts-jest

Running jest test I faced following issue:

`
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

```
      30 |   certificateEuropean: '/icons/certificate-european.svg',
      31 |   check: '/icons/check.svg',
    > 32 |   checkGold: '/icons/check-gold.svg',
```

`

This is the test:

`
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

```
import { Icon } from '@/components/UI/Icon';

describe('RegistrationForm', () => {
  test('should update and retrieve values correctly', () => {
    render(<Icon type="accreditation" />);
  });
});
```

`

This is the component:

`
const iconMap = {
accreditation: '/icons/accreditation.svg',
.
.
}

```
export const getIconSrc = (type: IconType): string => iconMap[type];

export const Icon = React.forwardRef<HTMLImageElement, IconProps>(
  ({ type, size, width, alt = '', id, quantity }, ref) => {
    const _size = size ?? 24;
    const _width = width ?? _size;
    const iconSrc = getIconSrc(type);

    return (
      <>
        <img
          data-testid={id}
          className="h-full"
          ref={ref}
          src={iconSrc}
          width={_width}
          height={_size}
          alt={alt}
        />
        {typeof quantity === 'number' && quantity > 0 ? (
          <span>
            {quantity}
          </span>
        ) : null}
      </>
    );
  }
);
Icon.displayName = 'Icon';
```

`

and this is my jest.config.js

`
// jest.config.js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

```
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test           environment
  dir: './',
});

const customJestConfig = {

  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],


  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '@@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '\\.(ttf|otf|eot|svg)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fontMock.js',
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ['./text-encoder.mock.ts'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['@testing-library/jest-dom'],
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);`
```

I tried adding following fields to jest.config.js
`
preset: 'ts-jest',
testEnvironment: //every possible option
transform: {
'^.+\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
},
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],

```
globals: {
  "ts-jest": {
    isolatedModules: true,
  },
},`
```

in package.json

`"type": "module",`your text 
run `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js` instead of `npm test`
result:
    `Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\USERNAME\frontend\node_modules\@sitecore-feaas\clientside\dist\browser\react.esm.js`

Comment: The same problem with `@sitecore-feaas`.
It's strange but when I set testEnvironment: 'node' this problem was gone (but node doesn't have `document` :) )

I've tried this but it didn't help:

``` lang-js
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!(^@sitecore-feaas)/)',
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like something wrong with `@sitecore-feaas` package.json — when I deleted "exports" field in `@sitecore-feaas/package.json` and did the same with `@sitecore/byoc` it started working.

I created a jest settings workaround:

jest.config.ts:

```ts
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/jest/sitecoreLibsExportFixing.ts',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/jest/sitecoreLibsExportFixingRestore.ts',
```

sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport.ts:

```ts
export const sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport = ['@sitecore/byoc', '@sitecore-feaas/clientside'];
```

sitecoreLibsExportFixing.ts:

```ts
import fs from 'fs';
import { sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport } from './sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport';

const sitecoreLibsExportFixing = (libsToPatch: string[]) => {
  libsToPatch.forEach((lib) => {
    const packageFilePath = `node_modules/${lib}/package.json`;
    const backupFilePath = `node_modules/${lib}/package.backup.json`;

    // Store a backup
    fs.copyFileSync(packageFilePath, backupFilePath);

    // Read the file
    const rawData = fs.readFileSync(packageFilePath, 'utf-8');
    const packageData = JSON.parse(rawData);

    // Remove the 'exports' property
    if (packageData.exports) {
      delete packageData.exports;

      // Write the updated content back to the file
      const updatedData = JSON.stringify(packageData, null, 2);
      fs.writeFileSync(packageFilePath, updatedData);
    }
  });
};

export default () => sitecoreLibsExportFixing(sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport);
```

sitecoreLibsExportFixingRestore.ts:

```ts
import fs from 'fs';
import { sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport } from './sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport';

const sitecoreLibsExportFixingRestore = (libsToRestore: string[]) => {
  libsToRestore.forEach((lib) => {
    const packageFilePath = `node_modules/${lib}/package.json`;
    const backupFilePath = `node_modules/${lib}/package.backup.json`;

    // Restore the backup file
    if (fs.existsSync(backupFilePath)) {
      fs.copyFileSync(backupFilePath, packageFilePath);
    }
  });
};

export default () => sitecoreLibsExportFixingRestore(sitecoreLibsWithWrongExport);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the other solution: mock `@sitecore-jss` in your test.
For example if your component uses `RichText` you can mock it like this:

```js
jest.mock('@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-nextjs', () => ({
  RichText: (props) => {
    return props.field?.value;
  },
}));
```